# How to add background colour in bars in chart.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, chart.js

All the examples are in simple java script on YouTube, no one I see in react.js

```
  const backgroundBar = {
    id: 'backgroundBar',
    beforeDatasetsDraw(chart: any) {
      const ctx = chart.ctx;
      const xAxis = chart.scales['x'];
      const yAxis = chart.scales['y'];
      ctx.save();
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'; // Set background color here
      ctx.fillRect(xAxis.left, yAxis.top, xAxis.width, yAxis.height);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  };
  const options: ChartOptions<"bar"> = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    animation: { duration: 500 },
    layout: {
      padding: 0,
    },
    scales: {
      x: {},
      y: {},
        ticks: {},
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Hours",
          color: labelColor,
          font: {
            weight: "bold",
            size: 12,
          },
          padding: 3,
        },
        suggestedMin: 0,
        max: 5
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: { display: false },
      backgroundBar: {
        id: 'backgroundBar',
        beforeDatasetsDraw(chart:any) {
          const ctx = chart.ctx;
          const xAxis = chart.scales['x'];
          const yAxis = chart.scales['y'];
          ctx.save();
          ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'; // Set background color here
          ctx.fillRect(xAxis.left, yAxis.top, xAxis.width, yAxis.height);
          ctx.restore();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return <Bar data={data} height={100} width={100} options={options} plugins={[backgroundBar]} />
}
```

Unable to set background colour here I want to add the background colour like the photo I provide you here , Kindly guide me if somebody can , thank you
[chart with bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQgN3.png)